# Difference between hermitian and conjugate linear sesquilinear form

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sesquilinear-forms

I am trying to work out the difference between hermitian and conjugate linear sesquilinear form. Let me elaborate on my confusion:

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. One definition (see e.g. [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0125113609) page 49) for sesquilinear form is that it is a map $H^2 \to \mathbb C$ such that it is linear in the first argument and conjugate linear in the second.

> My question is why is this not equivalent to this?:

A sesquilinear form is a map $H^2 \to \mathbb C$ such that it is linear in the first argument and such that for all $x,y\in H$ we have $\langle x,y\rangle = \overline{\langle y,x \rangle}$?

A sesquilinear form with the property $\langle x,y\rangle = \overline{\langle y,x \rangle}$ is called hermitian. Since we have extra terminology it would seem that one would define a sesquilinear map as a hermitian map that is linear in the first argument. But I looked and every definition I could find described it as a map "linear in the first and almost linear in the second argument". Which strongly suggests that my own idea for a definition is not equivalent.

Comment: If $(x,y)$ is the inner product then $s(x,y)=i(x,y)$ is linear in the first coordinate and conjugate linear in the second. However $\overline{s(x,y)} \ne s(y,x)$.

Comment: @T.A.E. Thank you very much, your comment is very helpful. If you could post it as an answer it would enable me to reward it using upvote and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(x,y)$ is the inner product then $s(x,y)=i(x,y)$ is linear in the first coordinate and conjugate linear in the second. However $\overline{s(x,y)}\ne s(y,x)$.